# Problems with mod_auth_token installation

Tags: c, apache2, apache2.4, apache2-module, apxs2

> TOOLS

```
 apache2 -v : Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
 ubuntu 14.04 LTS
```

<del>I'd like to install `mod_auth_token` to secure some of my files but I'm having problems with the first command I need to run:</del>

> Command

`./configure`

> Error message

```
configure: error: APXS not found in $PATH, please use with-apxs to specify the location of the apxs binary
```

<del>Except that `locate apxs` returns none so I guess it's nowhere and</del>

```
 echo $PATH -> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Any ideas ?

---

### UPDATE1

Found it, `apxs2` was missing, to add it `apt-get install apache2-dev`

But now when I run `make` or `make check` or `make install` I get a warning and the installation stops:

```
mod_auth_token.c:65:3: warning: missing sentinel in funcgtion call [ -Wformat=]
ap_set_string_slot(cmd, config, apr_pstrcat(cmd->pool, arg, '/'));
^
```

> Code

```
if (arg[len -1] != '/') {
  /*here*/   ap_set_string_slot(cmd, config, apr_pstrcat(cmd->pool, arg, '/'));
     conf->prefix_len = len + 1;
     ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and developer here figured this for me (thanks Bill!).

According to Apache Docs https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.6/group__apr__strings.html#ga7bd80c95ffb7b3f96bc78e7b5b5b0045 "The final string must be NULL"

He changed that line to:

```
ap_set_string_slot(cmd, config, apr_pstrcat(cmd->pool, arg, '/', NULL));
```

and it compiled.